# ListViews inside ListViews

Tags: android, listview

I have to implement something like that:
[image]
 "ListViews"

I call `month.setadapter(adapter)` once for each year but it's not working because the last month overwrites the information of the previous last one.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I normally do in a situation like this is implement it as a single custom adapter.

1. Derive from BaseAdapter
2. Set your data as a non-generic ArrayList.  You can fill your ArrayList with data representing your month rows and the detail rows within each month.  You need some way of differentiating them in the adapter, so wrap things in custom objects that allow you to do this.  In your example above, I'd say you can iterate through your data and insert a Date object each time you reach a row with a different month than the previous data row.
3. Your adapter should override getItemViewType and getItemViewCount.  getItemViewCount returns the total number of different view types (looks like you'll return 2 from this method).
4. In getView, take the position parameter and pass it to getItemViewType.  In getItemViewType, get the item in your ArrayList at the current position and test it for its data type.  Return a constant representing which type of data to display.
5. In getView, now that you have the data type to display, run code appropriate for this display - inflate the layout representing the appropriate row type and set the appropriate data on the child views of the layout.

All of this is covered in the "World of ListView" video from Google I/O 2010 that ALL Android programmers should watch at least once:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Hi again Rich, I have a doubt, the two types are "months" and "years" or these types are the two month of the line? Sorry for my english, I hope you can understand me. Thanks for help!